# Lotus Designer software, and command and Lotus Script - program flow

Tags: lotus-notes

I am new to lotus. I have a task. there is a reference number in a form. I have to find out how it is generated. I have found the logic but how to find answers for questions like 
1.Which script library running related Ref No generation 
2.Which event is running for ref No generation, and please explain in detail
3.Which view refer and generate Ref No.

Please explain.

Thanks,
Priya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you found the logic.  Okay... where is it?  Is it in a sub or function in a script library?  If so, then you need to find all the places that use that script library and call that sub or function.  You can use the database synopsis feature for this.  Open the database, pull down the File menu, select Application, and select Design Synopsis from the sub-menu.  Go through the choices in the Type drop-down, and click Add All for each one.  Then click OK.  You will get a dump of all the design information in the database in text form.  You can use ctrl-F to bring up a search box to search for the name of the sub or function that contains the logic -- or you can copy this text your favorite editor and use search functions there, which might be more to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

With the debugger you will be able to walk through the lotus-script code and understand what is happening.

Comment: I am sorry :( Can you please explain how?

Comment: Your question is very vague. But if you want to see what happens in a script, run the script with the debugger enabled. More info about the debugger can be found in the help.